# PFUser() and handling the password member

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I apologize for a really long question. Most of the code is redundant. Please take a look!!!

At first, I thought the specified information was sent in the else part as seemed to be indicated by the Parse documentation, https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users:

```
func myMethod() {
  var user = PFUser()
  user.username = "myUsername"
  user.password = "myPassword"
  user.email = "email@example.com"
  // other fields can be set just like with PFObject
  user["phone"] = "415-392-0202"

  user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
      let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
      // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
    } else {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    }
  }
}
```

Note, the "Hooray! Let them use the app now." So I thought as long as the control flow doesn't reach `else{}`, the specified information will not be sent to the cloud. But I was wrong. After much trial and error, this is the conclusion that I have arrived to. `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` sends the necessary information if `error` is equal to `nil`. Please correct me if I am wrong. Here is why. As long as the `username` member is unique and is in the form of "something@something.com", `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` will send the specified information to the cloud, **even if**, the other fields are empty.

The following code is quite redundant and I apologize for that. Just ignore all the `alertController` code.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        firstName.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {
        let user = PFUser()
        user["firstName"] = firstName.text
        user["lastName"] = lastName.text
        user.email = emailAddress.text
        user.password = password.text
        user.username = emailAddress.text

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if self.firstName.text == "" {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "please enter your first name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    //println("Handle Ok logic here")
                }))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else if self.lastName.text == "" {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "please enter your last name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    //println("Handle Ok logic here")
                }))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else if self.emailAddress.text == "" {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "please enter your email", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    //println("Handle Ok logic here")
                }))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else if self.password.text == "" {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "please enter a password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    //println("Handle Ok logic here")
                }))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else if let error = error {
                var errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
                errorString = String(errorString!)

                if (errorString?.rangeOfString("missing username").toRange() != nil) {
                    errorString = "missing email address"
                }

                if (errorString?.rangeOfString("username \(self.emailAddress.text) already taken").toRange() != nil) {
                    errorString = "email \(self.emailAddress.text) already taken"
                }

                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "\(errorString!)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    //println("Handle Ok logic here")
                }))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                println("SDFJPOIWEJRPOIJWEPOITPOEWIJRPOWIEJRPIWOJEPTIHWEPROIJWPEROIJ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, interesting thing is it seems that Parse should generate an `error` if the `password` member is empty since it is part of `PFUser()` as an `error` gets generated when `username` is empty. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

So the bottom line is: I don't want `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` to send the specified information to the cloud if the other fields are empty. And I'm not sure how to do that. Anyone have a suggestion to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your validation code outside of `User.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` callback:

```
@IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {
    let user = PFUser()
    user["firstName"] = firstName.text
    user["lastName"] = lastName.text
    user.email = emailAddress.text
    user.password = password.text
    user.username = emailAddress.text

    if firstName.text == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "please enter your first name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            //println("Handle Ok logic here")
        }))
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if lastName.text == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "please enter your last name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            //println("Handle Ok logic here")
        }))
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if emailAddress.text == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "please enter your email", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            //println("Handle Ok logic here")
        }))
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if password.text == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "please enter a password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            //println("Handle Ok logic here")
        }))
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                var errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
                errorString = String(errorString!)

                if (errorString?.rangeOfString("missing username").toRange() != nil) {
                    errorString = "missing email address"
                }

                if (errorString?.rangeOfString("username \(self.emailAddress.text) already taken").toRange() != nil) {
                    errorString = "email \(self.emailAddress.text) already taken"
                }

                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "\(errorString!)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    //println("Handle Ok logic here")
                }))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                println("SDFJPOIWEJRPOIJWEPOITPOEWIJRPOWIEJRPIWOJEPTIHWEPROIJWPEROIJ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work because I've tried the code in XCode and because as long as the `emailAddress` has a valid input, the `error` becomes `nil` and goes ahead and sends the information to the cloud. The control flow doesn't ever have to reach `else{}`.

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly are you trying to achieve? In your question you stated "I don't want signUpInBackgroundWithBlock to send the specified information to the cloud if the other fields are empty." Why this solution doesn't work? You want some additional validation?

Comment: The reasons why it doesn't work, I think, is as I just stated above. The latter reason about what I think happens with the `error` is not as strong of evidence that it doesn't work compared to that of the former reason that I mentioned which is, I copied and pasted the code and ran the program. It didn't work as in it still sent the information to the cloud even if the firstName, lastName, and password fields were empty. Hope I'm clear.